# Куда падает ударение в женской фамилии Ботрини?

Tags: орфоэпия, ономастика

Фамилия женщины Ботрини, на какой слог падает ударение?

Comment: _Екатерина: на какой слог падает ударение?_ === Думаю, на тот же, что у её мужа или её родителей.

Comment: Это зависит от возраста женщины.

Comment: Фамилия итальянская (ударение на предпоследнем слоге), но если от рождения живёт во Франции, может "ударяться" на последнем слоге.

Comment: @Alex_ander  А если в России? https://timiryazevskiy.mos.ru/presscenter/news/detail/7274778.html

Comment: Зависит от степени французского влияния (по отчеству она Анриевна, по мужу - Мухутдинова) - не будь его вовсе, ударение было бы однозначно на предпоследнем слоге. Для наиболее известного носителя фамилии в Греции (повар видного итальянского ресторана) оно осталось на месте (так в википедии), хотя его имя Этторе трактуется там на греческий манер (Гектор). Окончательно всё зависит от самой дамы, а так "французский" сдвиг ударения маловероятен, напр. Лино Вентуру (прожил большую часть жизни во Франции) это не затронуло (по крайней мере, в русском восприятии).

Comment: Это все рассуждалки... А у меня вот отец и дед делали ударение на разные слоги. И никакого влияния, кроме какого-то прапорщика, который сказал деду (дед был военный) "как надо".

Comment: @behemothus "Это зависит от возраста женщины." — это вы пошутили?